# how do i test the color of a pixel in p5.js

Tags: colors, pixel, p5.js, raycasting

i am making a simple raycaster in p5.js(making my own 3d) and i cannot find how to make it read the pixels color.

i tried to do

```
for (let m = 0; m < 30; m++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        sx += 1*sin(sdir);
        sy += 1*cos(sdir);
        let e = get(sx, sy, 1, 1);
        print(e);
    }
    line(sx, sy, x, y);
    sdir+=1;
}
```

sx, xy are defined and making the ray part, but i cant figure out how to make it read colors. i looked for a while in the docs, but there was nothing i could find. is it possible in p5.js to read pixel colors, or do i have to manually input areas for the ray to bounce on?
[the raycaster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ45E.png)

Comment: Since you're using `line`, maybe *To color a line, use the stroke() function*, [reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/line)

Comment: no, that's just so I can see where it ends up(I was trying to see if it would work like that). also, for some reason, it's making a circle?

Comment: Ah, I see, you're using `get()`. Not entirely sure about the end result, but maybe [pixels](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pixels) is better suited (also performance-wise)?

Comment: I'm going to look into that, I must have missed it. Thanks if it works!

Comment: however, how do i fix the circle?

Comment: I think this is missing a [mcve] and could use a better description of what problem testing a pixel's color is supposed to solve, to avoid an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). I've written raycasters before without testing pixel colors, so it's not clear to me why this requirement is necessary in this case.